# Android adb command for triggering custom receiver

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-shell

I have the following receiver which works perfectly well when the server initiates a push notification. I would like to be able to test it locally using the ADB. 
This is the command I'm using:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE --es com.parse.Data "Ipsum Lorem" -n com.jon.ticktock/.CustomParseGCMReceiver
```

And this is how the receiver is defined in the Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".CustomParseGCMReceiver"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

However the command does not seem to trigger this receiver.

Comment: I've edited the question (thanks)

Comment: You can try this:`adb shell am broadcast -a com.whereismywifeserver.intent.TEST --es sms_body "test from adb"`, might no need to specify receiver.

Answer (score 1):

You can test if you can receive broadcast step by step.

1. raw broadcast

`adb shell am broadcast -a com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE`

2. with extra

`adb shell am broadcast -a com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE --es com.parse.Data "Ipsum Lorem"`

3. with given component

`adb shell am broadcast -a com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE --es com.parse.Data "Ipsum Lorem" -n com.jon.ticktock/.CustomParseGCMReceiver`

To check which part is error.

Comment: none work. I know this because I have place a log in the onReceive method and it doesn't show.

Comment: @JY2k Two more check. 1. Check your  `android:name=".CustomParseGCMReceiver"` is correct point to `CustomParseGCMReceiver` class.  2. Test it on other device or emulator.

Comment: 1. don;t understand what you mean? 2. I've tested on multiple devices.

Answer (score 1):

When it is Receiver attribute of the "exported" "false", it can not be called directly.

> android:exported="false"

However, when the "true", I will crash in the initialization of Parse SDK "SecurityException".

**Parse.java**

```
public static void initialize(Context context, String applicationId, String clientKey) {
    ...
    if (!allParsePushIntentReceiversInternal()) {
    throw new SecurityException("To prevent external tampering to your app's notifications, " +
          "all receivers registered to handle the following actions must have " +
          "their exported attributes set to false: com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE, "+
          "com.parse.push.intent.OPEN, com.parse.push.intent.DELETE");
    }
    ...
}
```

**allParsePushIntentReceiversInternal**

```
private static boolean allParsePushIntentReceiversInternal() {
    List<ResolveInfo> intentReceivers = ManifestInfo.getIntentReceivers(
        ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_PUSH_RECEIVE,
        ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_PUSH_DELETE,
        ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_PUSH_OPEN);

    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : intentReceivers) {
        if (resolveInfo.activityInfo.exported) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you want to really send , you need to build without performing the initialization of Parse SDK. You can send a Broadcast in ADB.

```
//Parse.initialize(this, "PARSE APPLICATION ID", "PARSE API KEY");
```

You can call the "onReceive".

Answer (score 0):

delete `android:exported="false"` in the Manifest.

Because an unexported component can not be accessed via shell, unless it's a root shell. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html#exported